# Android Toast doesn't appear when I click on items listed in the Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-alertdialog

When I click on items listed in the AlertDialog, I want the Clicked Item to appear with Toast. But whatever I did, it didn't happen. **Nothing happens when clicking the Item**. thank you
This is the main file. I'm getting the data from the database.
**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
List<NuriClass> nurList;
public void favori_listele_class (String getir_kategori){
      SQLiteDatabase db = veritabanim.getReadableDatabase();
String[] getColumnName={"_id,kategori,bilmece,cevap,favori"};
 String[] arananDegerler={"1",getir_kategori};
Cursor imlec=db.query("bilmecebulmaca_tablosu", getColumnName, "favori=? And kategori=?",arananDegerler , null, null, null);
//Cursor imlec=db.query("bilmecebulmaca_tablosu", getColumnName, "kategori=?",arananDegerler1 , null, null, null);
final ArrayList<Integer> favori_listesi_id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
final ArrayList<String> favori_listesi = new ArrayList<String>();
nurList = new ArrayList<>();
while(imlec.moveToNext()){
int dizi_id=imlec.getInt(imlec.getColumnIndex("_id"));
String dizi_bilmece=imlec.getString(imlec.getColumnIndex("bilmece"));
String dizi_cevap=imlec.getString(imlec.getColumnIndex("cevap"));
int dizi_favori=imlec.getInt(imlec.getColumnIndex("favori"));
String dizi_soru= dizi_bilmece+ " "+dizi_cevap+ " "+dizi_favori;
favori_listesi.add(dizi_soru);
favori_listesi_id.add(dizi_id);
nurList.add(new NuriClass(dizi_id,  getir_kategori, dizi_bilmece, dizi_cevap,dizi_favori,R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
 }
ListeGoster((ArrayList<NuriClass>) nurList);
```

**I call the bottom one with ListeGoster at the top.**
**I get the data from the database here**

```
    private void ListeGoster(final ArrayList<NuriClass> ssss){
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nuri_list, null);
               alertDialog.setView(convertView);
               alertDialog.setTitle("FAVORİLER");
            
               alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.uygulama_8);
               alertDialog.setCancelable(true);   //Tıkladığında PENCERE KAPANSIN MI?
    final ListView listViewNur = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewNuri);
    final NuriAdaptor adapter = new NuriAdaptor(this, R.layout.nuri_modelim, ssss);
    if (listViewNur != null) {
        listViewNur.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        
 alertDialog.setPositiveButton("KAPAT", null);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButtonIcon(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_delete, getTheme()));
listViewNur.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The program does not show this toast when clicking on items. it never gets to this point.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 });
        
alertDialog.show();
```

**Nuriadaptor.java**

```
public class NuriAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<NuriClass>{
List<NuriClass> nuriList;   //KisilerCLASS türü Listedeki liste değerleri
Context context;
int resource;   //liste öğeleri için düzen kaynak dosyası, the layout resource file for the list items

//yapıcı değerleri başlatıyor, constructor initializing the values
public NuriAdaptor(Context context, int resource, List<NuriClass> nuriList) {
super(context, resource, nuriList);
this.context = context;
this.resource = resource;
this.nuriList = nuriList;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null, false);  //getting the view

ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
TextView textKategori = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewKategori);
TextView textSoru = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSoru);

FloatingActionButton favSil = view.findViewById(R.id.floating_sil_FAV);
NuriClass nuri = nuriList.get(position);    

textKategori.setText(nuri.getKategori());
textSoru.setText(nuri.getSoru());


//öğeyi listeden kaldırmak için düğmeye bir tıklama dinleyicisi ekleme, adding a click listener to the button to remove item from the list
favSil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
//seçilen değeri listeden çıkarmak için bu yöntemi arayacağız, we will call this method to remove the selected value from the list
//yöntemde kaldırılacak pozisyonu geçiyoruz, we are passing the position which is to be removed in the method
removeKisiler(position);

 }
});

//finally returning the view
return view;
}

//this method will remove the item from the list
private void removeKisiler(final int position) {
//Silme işlemini onaylamak için bir uyarı iletişim kutusu oluşturma, Creating an alert dialog to confirm the deletion
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Silmek istediğinizden EMİNMİSİNİZ?");
builder.setPositiveButton("EVET", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   //uyarıdaki yanıt olumluysa, if the response is positive in the alert
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
nuriList.remove(position);  //öğeyi kaldırmak, removing the item
notifyDataSetChanged();     //listeyi yeniden yüklemek, reloading the list
 }
});

//cevap olumsuz ise hiçbir şey yapılmıyor, if response is negative nothing is being done
builder.setNegativeButton("HAYIR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

 }
 });

//uyarı iletişim kutusunu oluşturma ve görüntüleme, creating and displaying the alert dialog
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
 }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxXZR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y37vI.png)

Comment: Your codes are a bit messy and confusing. For now, try ```sss.get(i).getTitle()``` if you have a getTitle method or something like that.

Comment: Does the click listener even get called?!

Comment: listViewNur.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The program does not show this toast when clicking on items. it never gets to this point.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

Comment: What are all these codes inside onItemClick? How do you populate the list? I see you using ```ssss``` but I don't see you initializing it. What's this "ssss"?

Answer (score 0):

I get the data from the database here

```
 public void favori_listele_class (String getir_kategori){
        SQLiteDatabase db = veritabanim.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] getColumnName={"_id,kategori,bilmece,cevap,favori"};
        String[] arananDegerler={"1",getir_kategori};
        Cursor imlec=db.query("bilmecebulmaca_tablosu", getColumnName, "favori=? And kategori=?",arananDegerler , null, null, null);
        //Cursor imlec=db.query("bilmecebulmaca_tablosu", getColumnName, "kategori=?",arananDegerler1 , null, null, null);
        final ArrayList<Integer> favori_listesi_id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        final ArrayList<String> favori_listesi = new ArrayList<String>();
        nurList = new ArrayList<>();
        while(imlec.moveToNext()){
            int dizi_id=imlec.getInt(imlec.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            String dizi_bilmece=imlec.getString(imlec.getColumnIndex("bilmece"));
            String dizi_cevap=imlec.getString(imlec.getColumnIndex("cevap"));
            int dizi_favori=imlec.getInt(imlec.getColumnIndex("favori"));
            String dizi_soru= dizi_bilmece+ " "+dizi_cevap+ " "+dizi_favori;
            favori_listesi.add(dizi_soru);
            favori_listesi_id.add(dizi_id);
            nurList.add(new NuriClass(dizi_id,  getir_kategori, dizi_bilmece, dizi_cevap,dizi_favori,R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        }
        ListeGoster((ArrayList<NuriClass>) nurList);
```